# json data check if same id repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, filter

I have a json data there one id has different color_id.
So from there I just want to check if same id repeat then just keep first one

Here is my sample JSON

```
var data= [{ "id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22","color_id": "22" },
    { "id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15","color_id": "1" },
    { "id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59","color_id": "22" }];
```

My desired output

```
var data= [{ "id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22","color_id": "22" },
    { "id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59","color_id": "22" }];
```

I tried reduce but there I found that modify data structure so I am not sure that I will get my desired output or not.

Comment: How do you want to decide what record to keep and what to delete?

Comment: @PavelMolchanov just want to keep unique id. not repeating same id. other value is not matter.

Comment: @LemonKazi it seems that your "id" isnt a primary key.  It would be more effecient if you could change it on the Endpoint itself.  That being said, there are ways to remove items where id match, but how would you define specifics?  are you trying to keep all items with color_id == 22, or ensure unique IDs, but if there is a collission how would i determine which is kept?  So would it be first instance in array wins, or is it a particular color_id, or what?

Comment: @Fallenreaper I can understand that for that reason I just needed id only other data not necessary to keep. I filtered data on my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "xxx",
    "age": "22",
    "color_id": "22"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "yyy",
    "age": "15",
    "color_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "zzz",
    "age": "59",
    "color_id": "22"
  }
];

let map = {};
let uniqueEntries = data.filter((el) => map[el.id] ? false : map[el.id] = true);
console.log(uniqueEntries )
```

**Explaination:**

1. You create a map where we store ids.
2. Then filter the array and everytime we find an entry that is not in the map we add it to the list and return true. If we already have it in the list we return false to discard that entry.

the last part of the conditional is using the fact that an assignment returns the assigned value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to create a new array and in this new array use `findIndex` to check if this new array has an object with same id. If there exist an object with same id then dont push another object with same id

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "xxx",
    "age": "22",
    "color_id": "22"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "yyy",
    "age": "15",
    "color_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "zzz",
    "age": "59",
    "color_id": "22"
  }
];
let m = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findIndex = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.id === curr.id
  })
  if (findIndex === -1) {
    acc.push(curr)

  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.reduce` and `Array.some`

```js
const data = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'xxx',
    age: '22',
    color_id: '22',
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'yyy',
    age: '15',
    color_id: '1',
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    name: 'zzz',
    age: '59',
    color_id: '22',
  },
];

const reduced = data.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  if (tmp.some(y => y.id === x.id)) return tmp;

  return [
    ...tmp,

    x,
  ];
}, []);

console.log(reduced);
```

---

Or `Array.filter` as it was a good idea from @JGoodgive, but kinda different

```js
    const data = [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'xxx',
        age: '22',
        color_id: '22',
      },
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'yyy',
        age: '15',
        color_id: '1',
      },
      {
        id: '5',
        name: 'zzz',
        age: '59',
        color_id: '22',
      },
    ];

    const reduced = data.filter((x, xi) => !data.slice(0, xi).some(y => y.id === x.id));

    console.log(reduced);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set` to keep track of the IDs already processed.

```js
const
  // The data set with non-unique IDs
  data= [{ "id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22","color_id": "22" }, { "id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15","color_id": "1" }, { "id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59","color_id": "22" }];
  
function dedupe(items) {
  // Create a set to keep track of IDs already encountered.
  const
    idSet = new Set();
  // Filter the items, when an ID isn't in the set add it to the set and return true
  // so item is in the result array. When the ID is in the set return false so the 
  // item will be dropped.
  return items.filter(item => {
    // If the ID is already in the set, drop it from the result. This way only the
    // first item with an ID is added to the result.
    if (idSet.has(item.id)) {
      return false;
    }
    
    // Add the ID to the set, this way we keep track of the IDs already encountered.
    idSet.add(item.id);
    // Return true so the item is included in the result array.
    return true;
  });
}    

console.log(dedupe(data));
```