# JS json array compare array and remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have below two arrays which are similar in structure except for additional key in the array `1` When I get array `2` I would like to remove duplicates from array `2` if they are already present in array `1`.

For e.g. *2nd* item is a duplicate.

### Array 1:

```
[{
  "from": "1",
  "to": "2",
  "text": "test",
  "_goid": "1234"
}, {
  "from": "3",
  "to": "4",
  "text": "test",
  "_goid": "12345"
}, {
  "from": "5",
  "to": "6",
  "text": "test",
  "_goid": "123456"
}]
```

### Array 2: (only difference is it does not contain key `_goid`)

```
[{
    "from": "4",
    "to": "8",
    "text": "test"
},{
    "from": "3",
    "to": "4",
    "text": "test"  
},{
    "from": "9",
    "to": "10",
    "text": "test"
}]
```

I have below code which removes duplicates if arrays are exactly same but not working for my case.

```
function removeDuplicatesJson(myArr) {
   var props = Object.keys(myArr[0])
   return myArr.filter((item, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex((t) => (
      props.every(prop => {
        return t[prop] === item[prop]
      })
    ))
    )
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: [
{
    "from": "4",
    "to": "8",
    "text": "test"
},{
    "from": "9",
    "to": "10",
    "text": "test"
}
]

Comment: it should remove the duplicate node from second array when checked with first array because it is already present.

Comment: See here for a very similar question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52206805/1244780

Comment: this is using same array. I have two different arrays so how can same be achieved?

Comment: Is there anything that identifies these objects in the array or do you have to compare all the object properties to know if it is a match?

Comment: Sounds like an **interview** question OP wants help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will do as you ask: remove any items from `arr2` which already present  in `arr1`:

```js
var arr1 = [{
  "from": "1",
  "to": "2",
  "text": "test",
  "_goid": "1234"
}, {
  "from": "3",
  "to": "4",
  "text": "test",
  "_goid": "12345"
}, {
  "from": "5",
  "to": "6",
  "text": "test",
  "_goid": "123456"
}]

var arr2 = [{
    "from": "4",
    "to": "8",
    "text": "test"
},{
    "from": "3",
    "to": "4",
    "text": "test"  
},{
    "from": "9",
    "to": "10",
    "text": "test"
}]


// create a flat array of values to test against:
var arr1_keys = arr1.map(item => item.from + item.to);
// ["12", "34", "56"]

// filter out the dups and create a dup-free array
arr2 = arr2.filter(item => !arr1_keys.includes(item.from + item.to))

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's what you want but it might help you.

1.
Faster but limited option (depends on the amount of data), only if you're sure about objects signature, the order of properties is important:

```
const removeDuplicates = (baseArray, toDedupe) => {
  const baseArrayFormatted = baseArray.map(({ _goid, ...restProps }) => JSON.stringify(restProps));
  return toDedupe
    .map(item => JSON.stringify(item))
    .filter((item) => !baseArrayFormatted.some(baseItem => baseItem === item))
    .map(item => JSON.parse(item));
}
```

2.
Slower but more accurate:

```
const removeDuplicates = (baseArray, toDedupe) => {
  const props = Object.keys(toDedupe[0]);
  return toDedupe
    .filter((item) => !baseArray.some(baseItem => props.every(prop => baseItem[prop] === item[prop])))
}
```

Keep in mind that there is no checking of objects signature, also there is a lof of validation missing (if it's really an objects, if it's a function etc, but I believe it's not the question here).